# Dealing with Orbital and Surface Cloakers AI might have

Tags: ios, ascendancy

I've only started to discover the game (the iPhone version). My attempts to take down Orbital Shields around enemy worlds have so far failed (I blasted them with Plasmatrons).

I assume I simply did not have enough weapon hits in before being shot down, but could an Orbital Cloaker have played a role (I don't know if there was one, but noticed that the AI builds them)? If yes, how to counter them?

Once I'm past the planetary defense, will my Invasion Modules M be effected by the presence of any Surface Cloakers, or do I just need to have # M > # Surface (Mega) Shields (number adjusted if Mega Shields, I think from 1 to 3)? If Surface Cloakers matter, how to counter them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orbital cloakers have no effect on attacking orbital structures, apart from making it impossible to tell how many there are. They aren't targeted unitil after all the shields and orbital weapons are gone.

You can still see if a planet is shielded by the coloured ring around it.

Surface cloakers do the same thing - they have no effect aside from hiding things. Surface shields still only require one more invasion module (but not knowing how many there are can be a problem).